# Can't sign out of TFS in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2017, team-explorer

I am trying to sign out of TFS from Visual Studio 2017. I am connected to two VSTS online accounts. Here are the lists of the things I did:

- Removing my username from *Visual Studio => Help => Register Product => All Accounts*
- Deleting the entire entries in *Credential Manager* (all items from Web and Windows)
- Removing entries from `TeamExplorer.config`
- Using *Team => Disconnect from Team Foundation Server*

And when I open Visual Studio, one VSTS account is still accessible, while the other is not. It's so frustrating and imposes an important security threat. Even using `Connection Manager` windows from `Team Explorer` I can see that no account exists there and no TFS URL is listed there. But I can still do everything with one of my accounts.

Any ideas to help me sign out?

**Update**: I don't login anywhere, but this entry keeps coming back in *Credential Manager*:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried Team => "Disconnect from Team Foundation Server"?

Comment: @Lennart, I didn't know about that option. However, I did it and it still gets connected easily again.

Comment: As a workaround you could try to change your password or re-enabele 2FA.

Comment: @renklus, nice workaround. I'll use that. But the underlying problem is still a security threat.

Answer (score 0):

If it is VSTS account, you should be able to sign out by the steps below:

1. Click on your profile in the up-right corner of VS.
2. Click "Account Settings".
3. Remove the credential that you have already signed in.

And you can also clear the `.IdentityService` folder under `%localappdata%`. VS2017 stores VSTS Account credential there.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but the *Account Settings* page you mentioned is just the same page as *Help => Register Product* and as I mentioned it doesn't work. Also removing `.IdentityService` folder didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @mohammadrostamisiahgeli Check if this thread helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47188210/clear-stored-tfs-credentials-in-visual-studio-2017