# Issue with checking in

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I get the following error when I try to check in my code on TFS:

[image]

I've tried removing the cache from appdata folder but the issue persists.

What can be wrong here?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio? What version of TFS?

Comment: Have you tried to clear the tfs related credentials from Credential Manager:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47188210/clear-stored-tfs-credentials-in-visual-studio-2017