# Visual Studio 2019 - old credential for Azure DevOps is cached and we can't get rid of it

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

We use Visual Studio 2019 with Azure DevOps and a Git repo for source control.  Our logins are our identities from our Azure Active Directory.

Over this past weekend, we migrated from one Office 365 tenant to a new Office 365 tenant, and with that came a new Azure Active Directory.  We transferred our custom domain name to the new tenant and it is now the same as it was on the old tenant.

The problem now is with Visual Studio 2019 - it seems to be caching our old logins.  We have uninstalled and re-installed VS, but it seems that doing that doesn't actually clear everything.  It looks like our old creds are still cached.

The reason I'm pretty certain that this is a Visual Studio-specific issue is that we are all able to login to our repos at visualstudio.com and we can see everything just as it was before the migration (we did the proper migration of Azure Active Directory within DevOps - that was successful).  Further, when you browse to our repo **from within Visual Studio**, it brings us to a completely different link and empty repo.

Does anyone know how we can completely clear all account caches from Visual Studio?  Uninstalling VS apparently doesn't do it.

Comment: This looks like a possible quasi-duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47188210/clear-stored-tfs-credentials-in-visual-studio-2017  We're trying this solution now to see if it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> how we can completely clear all account caches from Visual Studio?

We could clear the cache from the following aspects:

1. Clean Credential Manager cache: Go to `Control Panel`-> Click `User Accounts`-> Click `Credential Manager`-> Go to `Windows Credentials`, click the link Remove from vault to remove stored Azure devops credentials. Now, When you login into Visual Studio you will be asked to give credentials to connect Azure devops.
2. Clean team foundation cache: the folder path is: `C:\Users\username(Team Explorer user name)\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\8.0\Cache`
3. Delete cookies in browser: logout of account in Internet Explorer and then clear all Internet Explorer cookies and stored password as detailed in this blog: Changing Azure devops credentials in Visual Studio 2019, After clearing out the cookies and password, restart IE and then re-login to your account(or windows live account). Then start Visual Studio and try to reconnect to Azure devops, you should be prompted for a credential now.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

With the courtesity of https://www.koskila.net/how-to-nuke-the-identity-cache-in-visual-studio/

the following folder can be deleted to wipe out the cache:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\ (where username is your local user name)\.IdentityService
```