How to forget Team Foundation Server account on Team Explorer Visual Studio 2022
I'm working on incorporating Team Foundation Server into the company I work for. Connecting to our Azure DevOps Server instance, I logged in with the administrator account of that server, but now I don't know how to change the user I log in with
We are not using Microsoft Login from Visual Studio, just Server Users to connect.
I have tried to remove the previously added server but it no longer asks me for any type of login as it asked me the first time.

Does this answer your question? Remove TFS Connection From Visual Studio 2019

@RuiJarimba thanks for replying but it doesnt cause i dont charge the tfs proyects using Microsoft Login im using the server URL, but it doesnt ask me about login again
https://pasteboard.co/ztGL90OipHPo.png

I think I just found a possible solution, it was to delete the saved tfs account from the Windows Credential Manager and change it to another one, but I thought I would have some option from the IDE itself.
I found it in this post
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47198510/23989120

Thank you for sharing your solution! It's helpful to know that deleting the saved TFS account from the Windows Credential Manager and changing it to another one resolved the issue for you. However, it's worth noting that solutions involving system-level changes like this might not be ideal for all users, as they can have broader implications beyond the specific problem being addressed.
In future posts, it would be beneficial to provide additional context and details, such as any potential drawbacks or considerations associated with the suggested solution. Additionally, it's good practice to e
